# npm run build is not working and displaying only it's value

Tags: javascript, json, npm

I have run the **"npm run build"** command for the package build distribution but it's not executing and returning only it's script value from package.json file.

C:\Project\jdpcmobile_client\trunk>npm run build

> parts-mobile@0.0.1 build C:\Project\jdpcmobile_client\trunk
>
> grunt build

and my package.json file is :-

```
{
  "name": "parts-mobile",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "John Deere Parts Catalog Mobile",
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "~4",
    "body-parser": "~1.14.2",
    "underscore": "~1.8",
    "bower": "~1.4",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-angular-gettext": "~2.1.0",
    "grunt-closure-compiler": "0.0.21",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.2.0",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.7",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.3",
    "grunt-jsdoc": "0.6.7",
    "angular-jsdoc": "0.3.3"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "start-dist": "node server/server.js dist",
    "translate-extract": "grunt translate-extract",
    "build": "grunt build",
    "docgen": "grunt docgen"
  }
}
```

So, how to make **"npm run build"** execute Successful and how can we know that **"npm run build"** have been executed Successfully?

Any positive response will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance : @Praveen

Comment: You can try to install grunt globally and test if `grunt build` works.

Comment: Yes I have try with grunt build and it is executed successfully but how to know that npm run build have executed successfully? and how to install grunt globally?

Comment: To install an NPM package globally, run `npm install grunt-cli -g`.

Comment: I have run the command and getting this response : npm ERR! registry error parsing json. and after that I have run "npm run build" but still getting above 2 lines ,, so how to execute it?